# Unexpected Spacing between two divs

Tags: html, css

Why is there spacing between the image and the list? http://jsfiddle.net/ZPQUP/3/
Also how do make the `<li>` elements occupy as much space as they can? SO I don't have extra space in the last-child?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make the image `display: block;`.

Convert the list to a table with css, if support for IE6/7 is not required.

See http://jsfiddle.net/ZPQUP/9/

Answer (score 3):

That's because the image is behaving as an inline element.  Inline elements have space at the bottom for letters that hang down, like `j`, `g`, `q`, `p`, etc.

Using `display: block;` forces it to behave like a block level element.

```
#profile-grid img {
    height: 250px;
    width: 332px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For make the list item fill all the "ul" you can add width:33%; to the list item:

```
li.item {
    margin: 0px;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    height: 50px;
    border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
    display: inline;
    width:33%;
}
```